# Does PHP have autovivification?

Tags: php, perl, autovivification

Searching [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=autovivification) for autovivification gives no results. At the time of writing, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) claims that only Perl has it. There are no clearly definitive results when searching [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20autovivification) for "php autovivification".

This PHP code runs fine:

```
$test['a'][4][6]['b'] = "hello world";
var_dump($test);

array
  'a' => 
    array
      4 => 
        array
          'b' => 
            array
              ...
```

Can anyone provide a canonical answer (preferably with references) that PHP does have this feature, and any details such as the version it was introduced in, quirks, shortcuts etc?

Comment: That will work when you're assigning values. PHP will create that path for you. This works only when you're assigning values.

Comment: @JohnP same thing seems the case in the example on the wikipedia link for pearl.

Comment: @Till No idea what that pearl code was doing. It's all voodoo for me :)

Comment: `perl`, not 'pearl' :) I hope my answer helps you understand how perl does autovification on read operations.

Comment: Simple explanation, the Perl programming language was designed systematically according to a well-planned design from the beginning. PHP was not. Hence the concept has a specific name and meaning in Perl.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, PHP does have autovivification (and has had it for a long time), although it isn't referenced by that terminology.  [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) states:

> An existing array can be modified by
>   explicitly setting values in it.
>
> This is done by assigning values to
>   the array, specifying the key in
>   brackets. The key can also be omitted,
>   resulting in an empty pair of brackets
>   ([]).
>
> ```
> $arr[key] = value;
> $arr[] = value;
> // key may be an integer or string
> // value may be any value of any type
> ```
>
> **If $arr doesn't exist yet, it will be
>   created, so this is also an
>   alternative way to create an array.**

However, the documentation states that if you try to access the value of an unset array (or key), it will return an error:

> Attempting to access an array key
>   which has not been defined is the same
>   as accessing any other undefined
>   variable: an E_NOTICE-level error
>   message will be issued, and the result
>   will be NULL.

I have tracked down my old **PHP3** manual, which states this:

> You can also create an array by simply
>   adding values to the array.
>
> ```
> $a[] = "hello";
> ```

Comment: So the feature does exist but PHP.net doesn't name it, right?

Comment: Yes, I have traced it back to PHP3 as well. It is simply referenced as an "alternative way to create an array".

Answer (score 3):

Well not 100% if PHP supports autovivification but the syntax you posts works for the most part.

```
// Works as you have assigned a value of 'hello'
$a['a'][4][6]['b'] = "hello";
var_dump($a);
echo print_r($a,true);

// works as you have assigned a value of 'world'
$b[][][][] = "world";
var_dump($b);
echo print_r($b,true);

// ERROR: Cannot use [] for reading
$c[];
var_dump($c);
echo print_r($c,true);
```

Cannot use [] for reading: [Related Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820258/cannot-use-for-reading)

Answer (score 2):

in perl, items will autovivify upon inspection, assignment is not necessary.  The path of items necessary to get to the innermost requested key will be created upon inspection.  Note that the {d => undef} is entry is not actually created but is implied.

```
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use Data::Dumper;

   my %a;       # as is empty, equivalent to \%a is {};
   print Dumper %a;
   $a{b}{c}{d}; # \%a is now { b => { c => {}}}
                # returns an undef value.
   print Dumper \%a;
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = {};
$VAR1 = {
          'b' => {
                   'c' => {}
                 }
        };
```

perl array example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my (@b,@c);          # @b=(), @c=()
print Dumper \@b;
$b[3];               # @b=() aka unchanged.
print Dumper \@b;
$b[3][2][1];         # @b=(undef,undef,undef,[undef,undef,[]])
print Dumper \@b;
print Dumper \@c;
$c[3]=1  ;           # @c=(undef,undef,undef,1)
print Dumper \@c;
```

Output:

```
Useless use of array element in void context at -e line 7.
Useless use of array element in void context at -e line 9.
$VAR1 = [];
$VAR1 = [];
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          [
            undef,
            undef,
            []
          ]
        ];
$VAR1 = [];
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          1
        ];
```