# Set associative array value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems quite simple, but I can't figure it out.

In PHP, I could do something like this:

```
$number_children[reference_number - 1][$key] = value;
```

In Javascript, I need to do the same: set a value in an associative array, which is in a normal array.

I've tried this:

```
number_children[reference_number - 1][key] = $(this).val();
```

This didn't seem to work. What's a simple method of setting this value?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: "Obviously?" Actually, it should work. Can we see the *rest* of your code, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Does your browser show any error?

Comment: I bet you defined `number_children[i]` as a normal array, and not as an object: `[]` instead of `{}`.

Comment: @Idiqual: Makes absolutely no difference, save a little waste of memory.

Comment: Does PHP have auto-vivification? (I don't use PHP, but I know that JS does not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript arrays and "associative arrays" are different. In fact, Javascript people don't use the term "associative arrays", they call them "objects" (or "hashes").

So, you can do this:

```
number_children[reference_number - 1] = {};
number_children[reference_number - 1][key] = $(this).val();
```

But this can have unexpected results when you try to iterate it, due to `length` not being set:

```
number_children[reference_number - 1] = [];
number_children[reference_number - 1][key] = $(this).val();
```

Comment: Arrays and "associative arrays" are not different in JS. All arrays in JavaScript are just objects with a special overloaded `[]=` and `length` (and are thus associative arrays, or Maps, as well). However, I highly recommend keeping the ADTs and usage distinct. JS helps a little more than PHP in this aspect, although it can be abused any which way, because an Array is a *subtype* of a Map.

Comment: I simplified the picture a little bit. :-)

Comment: Why can't you do the latter? You can set arbitrary key names in arrays as well. Everything's an object.

Comment: Well, you can, but when you later will iterate the array, it will appear empty. That can be a surprise for beginners :-)

Comment: So the real answer here is that either option would make the code work because the main thing is you have to actually set `number_children[reference_number - 1]` equal to some sort of object with `... = {}` or `... = []` before you can set properties on it with `number_children[reference_number - 1][key] = ...` (The difference between arrays and other objects is a secondary issue.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you initializing the arrays?:

```
number_children = [];
number_children[reference_number - 1] = {};
number_children[reference_number - 1][key] = $(this).val();
```

Perhaps a jsFiddle would help show the problem.

Comment: +1 for the only answer that explicitly mentioned initialising the arrays/objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as associative array in JavaScript.

In PHP you have just arrays, which can be numerical, associative, or mixed. In JavaScript you have arrays or objects. **Arrays in JavaScript are not associative.**

Your code is perfectly fine if `number_children` is an array of objects. That means if this is array, which contains objects, which in turn have the property named as the value of `key` variable in your example.

Comment: An [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) is also known as a Map (or Hash), which is a property of objects in JavaScript. I prefer the term "Map" for this reason and, good coding dictates an Array-object is used like an Array, however it is very easy to blur the line in JS :)

Comment: @pst: So basically you are saying that "_associative array_" is "_object_" in JavaScript (but first lets distinguish `new Array()` from `new Object()`)?

Comment: That is correct. All objects in JavaScript function as Associative Arrays (or Maps), with the mapping String -> Any. An Array in JavaScript are a specialize subtype of an Object. `[] instanceof Array` and `[] instanceof Object` are both true. `{} instaneof Array` is false.

Comment: The "difference" is that array(-object)s have a special `[]=` operator that updates the `length` property (and also have nice access to the Array prototype so `push`, etc can be called on them). However, it is *still* a Map of String -> Any, which is why `for (var i in someArray)` is "often wrong" as it won't iterate indices (properties) that have never been assigned a value. `for (..in..)` iterates *properties* in an object, which does include assigned indices (properties) for array(-objects) :-)

Comment: @pst: Ok, so let me be clear about what I was trying to say :) By "_array_" I understand instance of `Array`, and by "_object_" I understand instance of `Object`, that is not instance of `Array`. The problem many people face when beginning coding in JavaScript and having only experience in PHP is: expecting instances of `Array` (`[]`) to behave as in PHP. Thus, I distinguished associative arrays from "numeric" arrays. And this was the main goal of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Post the actual problem code (with minimal required context) *including* any error message and/or [unexpected] symptoms.

---

As minitech has said: there is nothing "obviously" wrong with the code.

Anyway, I Just Learned (TM) that [PHP has some form of auto-vivification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962325/php-autovivification). JavaScript has absolutely *zero* auto-vivification.

Thus,

```
$number_children[reference_number - 1][$key] = value;
```

*Should* work in PHP assuming that `$number_children` and `$number_children[x]`:

1. Have not been set.
2. Have previously been set to an "array".

Since JS *does not* work like this, then per SpoonNZ's or Sergio Tulentsev's answers, the **object/array *must* be explicitly created before using the [] operator**. (See their answers for an example).

Happy coding.